# Неправильный запрос на вывод своих подписчиков

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня есть таблица `followers`, поля `follower_id` и `following_id` имеют связь с таблицей `users`.

- `follower_id` - кто подписался;
- `following_id` - на кого подписались;

Структуру таблиц я создал [здесь](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=50b1cd7ba06a547fa01495a15363ff45)

Мой запрос:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT F.FOLLOWER_ID, F.FOLLOWING_ID, U.NAME, COUNT(CASE WHEN F.FOLLOWER_ID = '47' THEN '47' END) OVER (PARTITION BY F.FOLLOWING_ID) > 0 IS_FOLLOWER
            FROM FOLLOWERS AS F
                LEFT JOIN USERS AS U ON (U.USER_ID = F.FOLLOWER_ID)
                    WHERE F.FOLLOWING_ID IN ('47','47'))
            SELECT FOLLOWER_ID AS USER_ID, NAME, IS_FOLLOWER
                FROM cte 
                    WHERE FOLLOWING_ID = '47'
                        LIMIT '19' OFFSET '0'
```

Что возвращает:

```
 user_id |    name   | is_follower |
------------------------------------
   52    | Teddy     |      f      |
   88    | Kaelthas  |      f      |
   59    | test1     |      f      |
```

Что я хочу получить:

```
 user_id |    name   | is_follower |
------------------------------------
   52    | Teddy     |      t      |
   88    | Kaelthas  |      f      |
   59    | test1     |      f      |
```

На пользователя `47` подписаны `52`, `88`, `59`. Сам пользователь `47` подписан на 52, 79, 80. Моя проблема заключается в том, что в 4 запросе выводиться `58:f`, `88:f`, `59:f`, я ожидаю `58:t`, `88:f`, `59:f`, так как пользователь `47` подписан на `52`.
Где я не могу понять, как мне правильно нужно вывести подписчиков пользователей  и подписавшихся на пользователей?

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и **минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе**.

Comment: Я показал что выводит запрос и что я жду. Код есть по ссылке, там и таблицы. Что не так?

Comment: Ссылки могут протухнуть. а вопрос на SO останется навсегда и без рабочей ссылки будет не ясно о чем он

Comment: Правила ресурса.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev Я все исправил

Comment: Наличие "где то там в таблице", даже не в самой выборке, неких записей никак не влияет на оконную функцию. count() over() работает только по записям, которые есть в выборке, т.е. прошли по условиям where. И если бы записи и были, то оно бы посчитало бы наличие 47 follower в том же окне (т.е. среди строк с данным following), что совершенно не соответствует тому, что вы хотите получить. В вашем случае я бы сделал left join той же таблицы с `f1.followig=f.follower and f1.follower.f.following`, т.е. подклеил обратную запись и ориентировался на ее наличие (или то же самое подзапросом)